# Set-to-Subset point cloud matching

Tags: c++, point-cloud-library, point-clouds

I have two point clouds, in 3d coordinates. One is a subset of the other, containing many less points. They are in the same scale.

What i need to do is find the translation and rotation between the two. I have looked at Point cloud Library, ["Iterative closest point"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterative_closest_point), and [Coherent Point Drift](https://github.com/gadomski/cpd), but these matching approaches both seem to expect the two point sets to contain mostly the same points, not have one be a smaller, subset of the other.

Can i use either of these, with adjustments? Or is there another algorithm to match a subset point cloud to a set?

Thank you.

Comment: You need enough equal points in both point clouds as correspondence to find a translation and rotation. You can't use these approaches with a subset which has no intersection.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. It is a literal subset, as in, it contains some of the points from the Set.

Answer (score 1):

Without having access to sample data, is kind of hard to recommend you a specific registration algorithm.

However, I'm pretty exicted nowdays about all the new "data-driven" registration approaches.

From my personal experience, I'm having awesome registration results using the approach of this recent paper:

https://arxiv.org/abs/1603.08182

Wich has source code avaliable here:

https://github.com/andyzeng/3dmatch-toolbox

As reported in the paper, it outperforms pcl-descriptor based registration approaches and I think that it may be suitable for your needs.

Comment: Thank you. I am on windows, so cannot use that library sadly. Have you come across any point matching approaches that will work in real time? i am having trouble finding something that can handle set to subset, and will run in real time (<30ms)